# Magento 2: change price on front end but save order as normal price

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm using a plugin to change the price on the front end to add £100 to the base price for products.

> XX/XX/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="change_product" type="XX\XX\Plugin\ChangeProductPrice" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

XX/XX/Plugin/ChangeProductPrice.php

```
<?php
namespace XX\XX\Plugin;
 
class ChangeProductPrice
{
    public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        return $result+100;
    }
}
```

This is working perfectly up to checkout where, at the cart, the price goes back to base price. To get around this I made a new di.xml in the following location :

> XX/XX/etc/webapi_rest/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="change_product" type="XX\XX\Plugin\ChangeProductPrice" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

With the above in place, the cart and checkout now have the extra 100 added to the price, but the order is actually saving with the extra amount, I just want it to appear as if this extra 100 is there on the front end but actually when it saves as an order it isn't included.

The value of 100 will eventually be changed with some logic to be a dynamic value so its not something I can just hardcode to remove.

Would an observer be a good approach to kind of throw the order away and re-build it programmatically? I don't like that sound of that but its all I can think of at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

getPrice is being called in total collectors, so the extra amount is also added to order.
You want to create a plugin to the view only, e.g.
a beforeRenderAmount of Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox class.
Optionally check price code and area in $arguments for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what do you mean by the second option by using $arguments?

Comment: $arguments is the second parameter in the original renderAmount method, and in before plugin, you would want to pass this $arguments as well, and you would have opportunity to inspect this $arguments and decide for which type of prices you want to alter the displayed amount.

Comment: Ive done this, i can get the product details and the price from the arguments successfully the problem is i want it to display this price right until the order is placed then save the order with the hidden price, do i need to dump the order and rebuild it all programmatically with an observer? this would not be ideal but it's all i can think of right now

Answer (score 0):

You just changed the price on the UI so when you save the order it won't take the displayed price. So you need to save the price of the product in the database along with the price you display

Comment: It's the opposite, it IS saving the price displayed and i don't want it ioo

Comment: You are using a plugin to save the displayed price. Please search for this plugin and remove it from your code

Comment: The plugin allows the "fake" price to be displayed right to checkout, then i want the real price to save to Magento. Ive already done it with the proforma but i cant get the order to save with the hidden price

Comment: In this case you can use event to add product to cart with custom price. Event: checkout_cart_product_add_after